# error: package path is not valid. valid system image paths are:ository... null

Tags: android, react-native, command-line, command-line-interface

I have installed the command line tools of android, correctly configured all environment variables.

When I am creating a virtual device with this command:

```
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
```

It gives the following error:

```
error: package path is not valid. valid system image paths are:ository... null
```

I have already installed the SDK tool : `sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"`

And accepted the licenses `sdkmanager --licenses`

But still it's showing the same error.

By the way, I am using it for react-native

Answer (score 30):

In order to resolve your issue, you need to first run the cmd `sdkmanager --list`. A list will be populated with installed & available modules make sure: you have installed

1. Build-tools `sdkmanager build-tools 30`
2. Platform-tools `sdkmanager platform 30`
3. System image `sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86"`
4. System image `sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"`

After installing or making sure the above are installed you can go ahead on creating avd.

5. Create an avd - `avdmanager create avd -n TestAVD -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86" --device "Pixel_4"`
6. List created avds `emulator -list-avds`
7. Start Emulator or AVD `emulator @TestAVD`

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you

Comment: one thing I didn't understood from this answer: OP mentioned "android-23", yet you replied with "android-30", why?

Answer (score 14):

I've resolved the issue by installing image first
like

`sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"`

and then it is possible to create the emulator

Comment: Thanks man this solve my issue.

Answer (score 5):

as you can't install windows without `windows image` or linux without `linux image` 
android **AVDs** are the same, you need to download the **image** first then you can install it

to download the image simply type this command in cmd :

```
sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

after it finish downloading, now you can install the avd using the command :

```
avdmanager create avd -n yourAvdName -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that avdmanager can not find the local image. Please try:

1. `cd YOUR_SDK_ROOT_DIRECTORY`
2. `avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"`

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully set up the Android emulator on macOS using command line tools, here are steps:

1. **Unzip Command-line Tools:**
   Place the command-line tools in your SDK directory:

   ```
   /Users/MYUSER/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest
   ```

   Ensure that the `bin` directory is at:

   ```
   /Users/MYUSER/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
   ```
2. **Set Environment Variables:**
   Define your environment variables. Add these lines to your shell profile file (like `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc`):

   ```bash
   export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/MYUSER/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
   ```

   Don't forget to replace `MYUSER` with your actual macOS username.
3. **Install System Images:**
   Install the necessary system images using `sdkmanager`:

   ```bash
   sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
   ```
4. **Create an AVD:**
   Use `avdmanager` to create a new Android Virtual Device (AVD):

   ```bash
   avdmanager create avd -n myEmulator -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" --device "pixel"
   ```
5. **Start the Emulator:**
   Launch the emulator with the AVD you created:

   ```bash
   emulator -avd myEmulator
   ```

Make sure to replace `MYUSER` with your username where applicable. This setup should help you get your Android emulator running without any hitches.